# Multiple Joins in Grid

Tags: atk4

I can use join in a grid, but for a single field.

I have the next problem..

I have a table that has two id fields referencig the same field on other table.

Example:

```
table1 id,name 
table2: iduser1,iduser2 (both are fk to id on table1).
```

I have this values on table 1

```
id: 1 -> name: user1 
id: 2 -> name: user2
```

and on table2 I have a pair of values 1,2

```
iduser1: 1
iduser2: 2
```

If I make a join like this

```
$g->dq->join('table1','table1.id=table2.iduser1')->field('table1.name iduser1')->field('table1.name iduser2')
$g->addColumn('text','iduser1');
$g->addColumn('text','iduser2');
```

The result is name of user1 twice on the grid, but not user1,user2

I have tested to add another join() but without success. 
Can I have some help or maybe some direction about what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: but why do you have 2 fks to the same table?

Comment: I think I'm not understanding. Do you think this is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform two joins.

```
 // primary table
$grid->setSource('table1');

 // Joins all tables
$grid->dq->join('table2','table2.iduser1=table1')
      ->join('table1 user2');

 // This is how you add fields from linked table
$grid->dq->field('user2.name name2');
$grid->addColumn('text,'name2','Linked User');
```